# Adobe Flash Media Server 4.5 cannot stream video

Tags: flash, windows-server-2003, flash-media-server

I am configuring some settings for the Adobe Flash Media in my client's server,
he is using Window Server 2003, and recently it has been upgraded to 4.5.

I have look into the development guide document, and want to change the video streaming folder  from the default location (rootinstall\applications\vod\media) to a brand new location (F:), which is a Network Drive.

After I have followed the tutorial in the development guide, change the config file (rootinstall\conf\fms.ini) for the correct VOD_DIR path and the rootinstall\applications\vod\Application.xml file, I cannot get the video streamed.
The video player just keep on loading and never success to stream the video out.

So could anyone help me on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I see you have mentioned that you have followed the instructions on the guide.

Since you are using Windows Server 2003 , the FMS Service may not been started.

To start the FMS Service , Start -> Run -> Type "services.msc" without quotes. 
Scroll down to see FMSHttpd,FMS,FMS Admin Server and Click to Start all those services.